# How to set the Assembly Version of .NET dll's from Wix 3.5?

Tags: dll, wix, version

We are using VS2010 with Wix 3.5
We create 3 merge modules and then 1 msi that bundles all of the merge modules together.
We would like to be able to assign assembly versions to each dll in the merge modules. All of the dll's in one merge module can have the same assembly version, but each merge module will have a different version.
We tried doing this using the Version attribute within the Module tag but this did not do the trick. We cannot see any version number on the dll's.
How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version info contained in AssemblyInfo.cs file. Each you DLL must have reference one AssemblyInfo.cs to use one version.

Comment: Thanks alexanderb, but I am trying to do this with WiX, not the source code itself.

Comment: @Mr. T., Wix is used to build installer packages.  Assemblies are built(and versioned) before they get to Wix.  You might look into MSBuild([AssemblyInfo Task](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.4.0/html/d6c3b5e8-00d4-c826-1a73-3cfe637f3827.htm)) to accomplish what you're after, Wix is definitely not the right tool.

Comment: @heavy, can't you version an assembly when using the Deployment Project of VS? That is why I was asking about WiX assigning the assembly version.

Comment: You can set the version of an installer package, but AFAIK there is no way to change the version of an assembly using MSI, even using a deployment project.